# Moving from engineering to astrophysics (postdoc)

Tags: postdocs, changing-fields

I have seen an interesting postdoc position in computational astrophysics (focused on planet formation). I am a PhD in engineering, and I do research on mathematical modeling of hydro/fluid dynamics and some MHD. The postdoc position is requesting experience with computational fluid dynamics. I have experience with all the approaches and methods listed in the job description, although with different applications, and my PhD course satisfy the requirements. However, I have never done research in astrophysics. The position would start in the end of 2021 so I’d have some time to read books and related papers.

Do you think it is doable or should I look at something closer to engineering?

Comment: How would this postdoc advance your career?  You're unlikely to learn enough astrophysics to qualify you for a faculty position in astrophysics, and the postdoc seems unlikely to advance your engineering qualifications.  (OTOH, what's the harm in applying anyway?)

Comment: Sounds like you have relevant experience to bring to bear. Give it a shot.